# Line bundle associated with a $1$-cocyle of holomorphic functions.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, foliations

I'm trying to understand the following extract:

> A holomorphic foliation by curves $\mathcal{F}$ of degree $r$ on the projective space is a bundle map $\Omega : H_{-r+1} \rightarrow T\mathbb{P}^n$, from the line bundle of Chern class $-r+1$ to the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^n$, defined up to multiplication by a non-zero scalar.
>
> This means that $\mathcal{F}$ may be defined by a family of holomorphic vector fields $\{X_\alpha\}$ on an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, satisfying the conditions $$X_\alpha = f_{\alpha\beta}X_\beta$$ on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$, such that the line bundle $H_{r-1}$ is the one associated with the $1$-cocycle of holomorphic and non-vanishing functions $f_{\alpha\beta}\in \mathcal{O}^*(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)$.

The extent of my knowledge is basically that $H_{r-1}$ is $\mathcal{O}(-1)^{\otimes(-r+1)}$ where $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ is the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$.

I can see that the cocycle associated with $H_{r-1}$ can be interpreted to be a collection of non-vanishing complex-valued functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (instead of the usual isomorphism-valued functions) given that the fibers are $1$-dimensional. So an expression like $X_\alpha = f_{\alpha\beta}X_\beta$ makes sense.

However, I can't see how to define the $X_\alpha$ from the map $\Omega$, or $\Omega$ from the $X_\alpha$.

Comment: Do you know what are the transition function of a line bundle (given a local trivialization)?

Comment: @ArcticChar I do.

Comment: @ArcticChar I did some reading on cocycles and edited the question.

Comment: So the jist here is that the sheaf of homomorphisms $\mathcal Hom(L,F)$ is, for $L$ a finite rank vector bundle and $F$ a coherent sheaf, isomorphic to $F\otimes L^\vee$, where $L^\vee$ is the dual. I wonder if you would have an easier time proving the more general result?

Comment: @TabesBridges Unfortunately I can't figure out how to apply that result to the question.

Comment: Let $L = H_{-r+1}$ and $F = T\mathbb P^n$. Then $L^\vee = H_{r-1}$, and the tensor product should be equivalent to the bundle whose sections are obtained by gluing vector fields (sections of the tangent bundle) using the transition maps of $H_{r-1}$.